# ON DUPLICATE value CONCAT VALUE with string

Tags: php, mysql, concatenation

English is not my native language and this is hard to me to explain so apologies in advance for bad grammar and/or typos.

I have a mysql table as it shows

```
+-----------------------+---------+---------------+---------------+------+
|        sus_key        | sus_nom |   sus_mail    |    sus_id     | etc..+
+-----------------------+---------+---------------+---------------+------+
|   int auto_increment  | String  | String UNIQUE |    String     | etc..+
+-----------------------+---------+---------------+---------------+------+
```

I use this table to save subscribers for newsletters and I use the "sus_id" to identify which form the user subscribed from, example:

```
user1 subscribe from form of page1 the "sus_id" will be "form1"
user2 subsribe from form of page2 the "sus_id" will be "form2"
```

The users can freely change their name and other data if they insert the same e-mail on any form using "ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE" mysql_querry from php:

```
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
$sql = "INSERT INTO correos (sus_nom, sus_mail, sus_id, sus_tel)    VALUES ('".$name ."', '".$email ."', 'form#', '".$tel ."') ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE sus_nom = ('".$name."'), sus_tel = ('".$tel."'), sus_id = ('form#');";
$conn->query($sql);
```

what I want is if a existing user update from another form using CONCAT to mix the value of existing id_fom where the user subscribed with the id_form the user is actualy suscribing:

```
user1 suscribe in form 1 -> sus_id = "form1"
user1 update in form 2 -> sus_id = "form1form2"
```

and sorry if this turn out to be 2 questions but:
How do i use CONCAT on "ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE" statment?
Considering a user might subscribe to the same form twice, how to check if the value sus_id already has the current form_id string so values does not repeat? (if sus_id has "form1form2" and user update from form1 do nothing)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's generally a bad idea to put multiple values in a single column, it makes searching for values expensive because they can't be indexed, and as you can see from this question it makes updating the column difficult. But if you have to do it:

```
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE 
    sus_nom = VALUES(sus_num), 
    sus_tel = VALUES(sus_tel), 
    sus_id = IF(LOCATE(VALUES(sus_id), sus_id), sus_id, CONCAT(sus_id, VALUES(sus_id)))
```

`LOCATE` tests whether the new value of `sus_id` is already in the `sus_id` column. If it is, it sets `sus_id` back to itself, otherwise it concatenates the new `sus_id`.

BTW, notice that you can use `VALUES(colname)` in the `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` clause to refer to the values that would have been inserted into that column, rather than concatenating the string again.

Comment: I think you meant IF(LOCATE( VALUES(sus_id), sus_id)... right?